# Active Admin create a button inside a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to add a column that contains a button, not really sure how to go about this.

```
panel "Tool Details" do
  table_for tooling_request.add_tray_to_requests do |t|
    t.column("Tray") { |add_tray_to_requests| link_to add_tray_to_requests.tray.name, admin_tray_path(add_tray_to_requests.tray) }
    t.column("Number Needed") { |add_tray_to_requests| add_tray_to_requests.number_needed }
    t.column("Special Instructions") { |add_tray_to_requests| add_tray_to_requests.special_instructions }
  end
end
```

Comment: Where, specifically, are you trying to add a button? And are you talking about an HTML button or a link styled like a button?